# Boost Asio io_service destructor hangs on OS X

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, boost, boost-asio

I have a problem with Boost Asio on OS X, where the io_service destructor *sometimes* hangs indefinitely. I have a relatively simple repro case:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    std::time_t t = tv.tv_sec;
    std::tm curr;
    // The call to gmtime_r _seems_ innocent, but I cannot reproduce without this
    std::tm* curr_ptr = gmtime_r(&t, &curr);

    {
        boost::asio::io_service ioService;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(ioService);

        ioService.post([&](){
            // This will also call gmtime_r, but just calling that is not enough
            timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
            timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &) {});
        });
        ioService.post([&](){
            ioService.post([&](){});
        });

        // Run some threads
        boost::thread_group workers;
        for (auto i=0; i<3; ++i) {
            workers.create_thread([&](){ ioService.run(); });
        }
        workers.join_all();
    } // hangs here in the io_service destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, this just posts two handlers on the queue, one of which schedules a timer and the other just posts another handler. Sometimes this simple program causes the `io_service` destructor to hang indefinitely, in particular in the `pipe_select_interrupter` destructor during the `kqueue_reactor` destruction. This blocks in the system call `close()` on the pipe read descriptor.

To trigger the error I invoke the program in a loop using a shell script (but it is possible to trigger using a loop in the example above as well):

```
#!/bin/csh
set yname="foo"
while ( $yname != "" )
    date
    ./hangtest
end
```

I am no longer able to reproduce if I:

- Remove the call to `gmtime_r()` in the beginning (!). Edit: This only appears to apply if I run using the script. If I instead add a loop in the program itself I can reproduce it without that call as well, as per the comment by ruslo.
- Remove the call to `async_wait()` on the timer in the handler or move the timer setup outside of the handler.
- Remove the `post()` in the second handler.
- Lower the number of threads.
- Place a mutex in `kqueue_reactor::interrupt()`. This function is invoked from both the `async_wait()` and the `post()`, and calls `kevent()` with the read descriptor that is then not possible to close.

**Am I doing something wrong in the above code?**

I am running on OS X 10.8.5 with Boost 1.54 and compiling with `clang -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11`. I can also reproduce with Boost Asio from Boost 1.55 (with the rest of Boost 1.54 kept as-is).

Edit: I can reproduce on OS X 10.9.1 as well (using the same executable).

Comment: Confirmed. A little bit simplified version that I've tried with loop (to verify in one shot) and without gmtime_r: [link](http://pastebin.com/Sz7Ke6Mj)

Comment: @ruslo: Awesome, thanks - I have not been able to reproduce without the gmtime_r call so far, but I will give that another try.

Comment: @ruslo: Interestingly enough, I was unable to reproduce without the gmtime_r call if I was running using the script (I ran it for about an hour). But if I run using the for loop like in your example, I am able to reproduce it even without the gmtime_r call.

Comment: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this was committed to Asio in the master branch April 29th 2014

- https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/commit/3f473548a7d71012a77cd256a61034a505696958

> #### Fix occasional close() system call hang on MacOS.
>
> Repeated re-registration of kqueue event filters seems to behave as
>   though there is some kind of "leak" on MacOS, culminating in a suspended
>   close() system call and an unkillable process. To avoid this, we will
>   register a descriptor's kqueue event filters once only i.e. when the
>   descriptor is first created.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for taking the time to write this answer - I had forgotten to post this information here. Note that this fix is also in Boost 1.56 and later (but if I recall correctly caused an issue on some operating systems that was then fixed in 1.57).